# Read_gms permission error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-securityexception

I am developing a google maps application it works fine with android marshmallow in emulator but it shows error when running in android Ics 4.03 emulator it shows error. 
I tried installing `playstore` and `play services` in `emulator`
Thanks in advance

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10044 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10044 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1238)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1267)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:418)
        at com.google.android.gsf.f.c(SourceFile:107)
        at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:121)
        at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:227)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.b.m.a(SourceFile:304)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.b.f.a(SourceFile:222)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.b.e.c(SourceFile:200)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:92)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
           

 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
            

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           

 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
           

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           

 at `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
           

 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

**This is my manifest file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mema_labs.com.thirdeye">
<permission
    android:name="com.mema_labs.com.thirdeye.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.mema_labs.com.thirdeye.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!--uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/-->

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.mema_labs.com.thirdeye.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY" />


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TempActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:noHistory = "true"
        ></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        ></activity>




</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `logs` are stating it clearly that you are missing a `permission`.

Comment out this permission:

```
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove comments from this line

```
<!--uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/-->


<!-- Anything in between these will be considered as comments -->
```

so remove them and then try.